# Django Queryset with annotate

Tags: python, django, database, django-annotate

I am writing one method in Django Manager model.
I want to write method that finds out number of all sold copies (books) per author.

I have two models and method written in **Manager**.
My problem is that method should also be chainable from any Author queryset, for example something like

```
Author.objects.filter(...).exlucde(...).total_copies_sold()
```

should also work.

Example:

```
author = Author.objects.create(...)
Book.objects.create(..., author=author, copies_sold=10)
Book.objects.create(..., author=author, copies_sold=20)

author_total_books = Author.objects.total_copies_sold().first()
>>> author_total_books.copies
30
```

Below my code. It works like in example above, but then I try something like:

```
author_books = Author.objects.filter(id=2).total_copies_sold()
```

I got

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'annotate'

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):

    def total_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate(copies=Sum('book__copies_sold')



class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    objects = AuthorManager()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
```

**[Edited]**

Thank you schillingt for reply. I added:

```
class AuthorQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def total_copies_sold(self):
        return self.annotate(copies=Sum('books__copies_sold'))
```

I tried something like:

```
author_books = Author.objects.filter(id=2).total_copies_sold()

>>> author_books.copies
```

I got

> 'AuthorQueryset' object has no attribute 'copies'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are lookig for is :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce


class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate_with_copies_sold()


class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.annotate(copies_sold=Sum('books__copies_sold'))


class Author(models.Model):
    objects = AuthorManager()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
```

Now it is possible to chain queries e.g.:

```
author_total_books = Author.objects.total_copies_sold().first()
```

However you will no be able to use it on QuerySet object like:

```
author_books = Author.objects.filter(id=2).total_copies_sold()
```

That is because you are annotating Author object, not a QuerySet. To obtain that result you should execute:

```
Author.objects.annotate_with_copies_sold().get(id=2)
author.copies_sold 
15
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate_with_copies_sold()

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        # Write your solution here
        return self.annotate(copies_sold=Coalesce(Sum('books__copies_sold'), 0))


class Author(models.Model):
    # Make sure this manager is available.
    objects = AuthorManager()
    # objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(AuthorQuerySet)()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='books')
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Manager.from_queryset` to set your manager. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset).

```
class AuthorQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def total_copies_sold(self):
        ...

class Author(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(AuthorQueryset)()
```

Comment: or `objects = AuthorQueryset.as_manager()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods))

Answer (score 0):

```
class AuthorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AuthorQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.get_queryset().annotate_with_copies_sold()

class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.annotate(copies_sold=Sum('Book_Author__copies_sold'))


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    objects = AuthorManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Author" 
        verbose_name = 'Author'
        ordering = ('first_name','last_name')

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Book_Author')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Book" 
        verbose_name = 'Book'
        ordering = ('title','copies_sold')




from vehicles.models import Author, Book
try:
    author  = Author.objects.get(first_name='Mark', last_name='Twain')
except Author.DoesNotExist:
    author  = Author.objects.create(first_name='Mark', last_name='Twain')

try:
    book = Book.objects.get(author=author, title='Adventrure of Huckleberry Finn', copies_sold=7)
except Book.DoesNotExist:
    book = Book.objects.create(author=author, title='Adventrure of Huckleberry Finn', copies_sold=7)
    pass
try:
    book = Book.objects.get(author=author, title='Adventrure of Tomm Saywer', copies_sold=4)
except Book.DoesNotExist:
    book = Book.objects.create(author=author, title='Adventrure of Tomm Saywer', copies_sold=4)
    pass

author = Author.objects.annotate_with_copies_sold().first()
print(author.copies_sold)
11

1.Create AuthorManager, AuthorQuerySet classes from Author and Books
2.Create Author, Book models 
3.Prepare Test Data and use model manager to filter the queryset
```

Comment: can you add some explanation instead of code dumping

Answer (score 0):

**Count books sold by authors using Django ORM**

Wihtout writing custom manager you can use "AuthorQueryset" in Author Manager

Just a menthion AuthorQueryset.as_manager() in Author models, that's it.

Here are the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods)

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

# Create your models here.
class AuthorQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_with_copies_sold(self):
        return self.annotate(copies_sold=Coalesce(Sum('books__copies_sold'),Value(0)))

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    objects = AuthorQuerySet.as_manager()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    copies_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="books")
```